# Django индексирование поиска или ввожу пару символов и поиск предлагает варианты

Tags: python, django

В общем заглавие говорит само за себя. Помогите хоть что то найти по данному вопросу. Куча примеров по поиску, но именно с выводом результатов при "посимвольном" вводе не встретил(

Для примера: пользовался подсказкой создания поиска [отсюда](https://python-scripts.com/django-search)

Если я не верно выразился, или что то не понятно, вот пример отражающий всю идею вопроса.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в чем именно сложность? Сделайте кнопку, повесьте на нее обработчик ввода, при каждом новом символе, отправляйте ajax запрос на сервер и вернувшийся ответ выводите на экран

Comment: Сложность в том, что я открыл джанго 2 дня назад)

Comment: Но за наводку спасибо